# On random subset combinatorics.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics, extremal-combinatorics, coupon-collector

Suppose we have $2^n$ elements in a set. We have $cn^\beta$ random subsets of cardinality $\frac{2^n}{c}$ elements each where $c,\beta>1$ holds.

Fix a random subset of $n^\alpha$ elements $A$ where $\alpha>1$.

**(1)** What is the probability that there is at least one subset which will pick every element in $A$?

**(2)** How many subsets of size $n^\alpha$ distinct elements are not covered by any of the $cn^\beta$ subsets?

**(3)** What is the minimum number of subsets to cover every subset of size $n^\alpha$ elements?

Comment: I don't understand this. Is $c>1$? Why would you perform more experiments than there are elements in the set?

Comment: But if you are performing more than $2^n$ experiments, wouldn't it be easier just to look at every element in the set?